# howto spec not all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I know

```
rake spec:models
```

to spec all models.

Is there a way to spec only one model, or only a given collection of models?
Something like this would be desirable:

```
rake spec:model user
```

or with a collection of models

```
rake spec:model user role order
```

BTW: Brian Hogan wrote created something similar ([see here](http://github.com/napcs/lazy_developer)) but maybe there is something built-in in rspec2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the rspec command line ( with Rspec 2)

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

or if you want several

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb spec/models/role_spec.rb
```

If you want a task for that create. it.

Comment: hmm. $ rake spec spec/models/user_spec.rb still executes all specs

Comment: You don't use the rake command. It's the spec command. So without rake in your command line

Comment: spec: command not found. But it works fine with /Users/agreif/usr_local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby -S bundle exec rspec  "./spec/models/person_spec.rb"

Comment: Yes spec is to rspec 1 it's rspec on Rspec 2